# string.erase function is not working in a specific case

Tags: c++, string, erase

I have strings of the following format: "name.bag.csv"
I would like to remove the ".bag" from the string. 
This is an example of the code that I am trying to run:

```
csv_file_name = "loololololool.bag.csv";
csv_file_name.erase(csv_file_name.end()-8, 4);
std::cout << csv_file_name << std::endl;
```

But I get an error on the second line:

```
 no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int)’
         csv_file_name.erase(csv_file_name.end()-8, 4);
```

It seems to only take one argument.
However if I do:

```
csv_file_name = "loololololool.bag.csv";
csv_file_name.erase(13, 4);
std::cout << csv_file_name << std::endl;
```

it seems to work fine. Also when I execute

```
csv_file_name = "loololololool.bag.csv";
csv_file_name.erase(csv_file_name.end()-8);
std::cout << csv_file_name << std::endl;
```

It deletes the single character as it should. 
How can this happen? The `csv_file_name.end()-8` must be working as it deletes the single character. And taking two arguments should be working as well. But the combination doesn't? Please help!

Comment: Try [reading the manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), it's all explained there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up iterators and indexes.

- string.erase(iter) // delete the character pointed to by the iterator
- string.erase(iter1, iter2) // delete the characters between the two iterators
- string.erase(index, count) // delete count characters starting at index

`csv_file_name.end()-8` is an iterator and there is no version of `erase` that takes an iterator and an index or count.

Instead of

```
csv_file_name.erase(csv_file_name.end()-8, 4);
```

I think you meant

```
csv_file_name.erase(csv_file_name.size()-8, 4);
```

But really you should be able to read documentation and figure this stuff out for yourself. You'll be a lot more efficient that way.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it makes more sense to me now and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the singatures of std::string::erase. There is overloads that work with one or two integer positions, and another set of overloads that works with one or two iterators, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

What you are trying to do is call erase with a signature (iterator, integer). This overload simply does not exist.

**edit** too late :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I indeed managed to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
/*
  I have used this for this demonstration. However, it is
  not recommended to write this in larger projects. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice 
*/
int main() {
    //I have taken the position of the first dot. This is the position
    //from where I am deleting 4 characters including the first dot.
    //This holds true given the structure of the string is as below.
    //Please note that as long as the string follows this structure
    //<any number of characters>.bag<any number of characters> this will pass.
    string s1 = "loololololool.bag.csv";
    string s2 = "loololololool.bag.csv";

    cout << "Demo 1 Analysis \n";
    //Please consult this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/
    //Demo signature #1 string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);-------
    int posFirstDot1 = s1.find('.');
    string result1 = s1.erase(posFirstDot1, 4);
    cout << s1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of result1 : " << &result1 << " and address of s1 : " << &s1 << endl;
    //Note that result1 and s1 are same but are present at different addresses. Thats Subtle :)
    //----------------------------------

    cout << "Demo 2 Analysis\n";
    //Demo signature #3 iterator  erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
    int posFirstDot2 = s2.find('.');
    //get an iterator with s.begin() and posFirstDot3
    auto itFirstDot2 = next(s2.begin(), posFirstDot2);
    //we want to delete the next 4 characters starting from position of first dot
    auto itLastCharacterToBeRemoved = next(itFirstDot2, 4);
    auto result3 = s2.erase(itFirstDot2, itLastCharacterToBeRemoved);
    cout << s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```